# Why "it" instead of "them" in "make it into"?

Tags: verbs

In [this report news](https://www.chinadaily.com.cn/a/201909/27/WS5d8d3bf5a310cf3e3556db8b.html), there is a sentence about ports:

> Seven Chinese ports made ***it*** into the top 10 ports in the world in
>   terms of container throughput in 2018.

Why "it" is used? Should we use "them" because "ports" is plural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *[make it](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/make-it)* is an idiomatic expression meaning, as Macmillan has it,

> to succeed in a particular activity

The "it" does not refer to the subject, but to the fact of some achievement, milestone, or cutoff being met. This may be compared with other uses of *make* meaning to attain an objective, like making a deadline or making the team. According to the OED, these uses are derived from the nautical sense of *make it* meaning to reach a certain place or cover an intended distance successfully.